# React-Native cannot import library

Tags: javascript, import, react-native, importerror, ethereum

I'm trying to import the Ethereum [web3.js library](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API) into a React Native project.

I've followed the React [Linking Libraries](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking-libraries-ios.html) instructions, installing the web3.js package and linking it with the commands:

```
$ npm install web3 --save
$ react-native link
```

My `index.ios.js` file looks as follows:

```
import { default as Web3 } from 'web3';

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Text } from 'react-native';

class ReactProject extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Text>Hello world!</Text>
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('ReactProject', () => ReactProject);
```

The error message I receive in the simulator when I run the app  `{"type":"InternalError","message":"react-packager has encountered an internal error, please check your terminal error output for more details"}` is not very helpful as the terminal shows only the same message.

How do I go about importing libraries like this into React Native?

Comment: You only need to link libraries that use native code. packages with html/css also don't work but this doesn't seem to have that. try closing your packager and re-running your app.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try this instead to import the library:

`var Web3 = require('web3');`

Comment: **Fixed:**  https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/576


Edit The Following File


 /node_modules/bignumber.js/bignumber.js

edit as follows:

 -if ( !crypto ) try { crypto = require('crypto'); } catch (e) {}
 +if ( !crypto ) try { crypto = require('crypto-js'); } catch (e) {} 
 
**Web3 Version: 0.18.2**

Answer (score 0):

I created a step-by-step simple guide on how I set up `web3.js 1.0.0-beta.24` with `Create React Native App`, without modifying `node_modules`:

https://gist.github.com/dougbacelar/29e60920d8fa1982535247563eb63766

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make it work on web3 version 0.x and open sourced the solution creating [babel-preset-react-native-web3](https://github.com/agrcrobles/babel-preset-react-native-web3) so that it works out of the box, it might not be considered 100% secure if using for creating an account since it uses `Math.Random()` behind scenes.

For more info see the following [sample app](https://gitlab.com/dapps/react-native-web3-sample) using `web3 version 0.20.0`, `react 16` and `expo`.

Hope that helps,

Answer (score -2):

**Fixed:**  https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/576

Edit The Following File

```
/node_modules/bignumber.js/bignumber.js
```

edit as follows:

```
-if ( !crypto ) try { crypto = require('crypto'); } catch (e) {}
+if ( !crypto ) try { crypto = require('crypto-js'); } catch (e) {}
```

**Web3 Version: 0.18.2**